Proving $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} \frac{\cos y-\sin 2y}{\cos x\cos y}=1$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method

I'm trying to prove the limit
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} \frac{\cos y-\sin 2y}{\cos x\cos y}.
$$

Since
$$
\frac{\cos y-\sin 2y}{\cos x\cos y} 
= \frac{\cos y - 2\sin y\cos y}{\cos x\cos y} 
= \frac{\cos y(1 - 2\sin y)}{\cos x\cos y} 
= \frac{1 - 2\sin y}{\cos x},
$$
the limit is
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} \frac{1 - 2\sin y}{\cos x}.
$$
Along $x = \pi$,
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} \frac{1 - 2\sin y}{\cos x} 
= \lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} 2\sin y - 1 = 1.
$$
Along $y=\pi/2$,
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} \frac{1 - 2\sin y}{\cos x} 
= \lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,\pi/2)} - \frac{1}{\cos x} = 1.
$$
Assume that the limit is equal to $1$. For all $\epsilon>0$, we have to find $\delta>0$ s.t.
$$
0 < \sqrt{\left(x-\pi\right)^2 + \left(y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} < \delta 
\implies 
\left|\frac{1 - 2\sin y}{\cos x} - 1\right| < \epsilon.
$$
Now,
$$
0 < \sqrt{\left(x-\pi\right)^2 + \left(y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} < \delta 
\implies 
0 < \left|x-\pi\right| < \delta, \quad 
0 < \left|y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right| < \delta
$$
and
$$
\left|\frac{1 - 2\sin y}{\cos x} - 1\right| 
= \left|\frac{1 - 2\sin y-\cos x}{\cos x}\right| 
= \frac{\left|1 - 2\sin y-\cos x\right|}{\left|\cos x\right|}.
$$
I tried this way:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|1 - 2\sin y-\cos x\right| 
&= \left|1 - 2\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right) 
- \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right| \\
&\leq \left|1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right| 
+ \left|\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right) 
+ \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right| \\
&\leq \left|1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right| + 2 \\
&\leq 2\left|\sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{y}{2}\right)\right| 
+ 2 \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\left|y-\frac{\pi}{2}\right| + 2 \\
&< \frac{1}{2}\delta^2 + 2 
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|1 - 2\sin y-\cos x\right| < \frac{1}{2}\delta^2 + 2
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\cos x\right| &= \left|\cos \left(\pi-x\right)\right| \\
&= \left|1-2\sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right| 
\leq 1 + 2\left|\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right|^2 \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left|x-\pi\right|^2 \\
&< 1 + \frac{1}{2}\delta^2
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|\cos x\right| < 1+\frac{1}{2}\delta^2 
\implies 
\frac{1}{\left|\cos x\right|} 
> \frac{1}{1+\frac{\delta^2}{2}} 
= \frac{2}{2+\delta^2}
$$
But,
$$
\frac{2}{2+\delta^2} < \frac{1}{\left|\cos x\right|}, 
\qquad 
\left|1 - 2\sin y-\cos x\right| < \frac{1}{2}\delta^2 + 2
$$
so
$$
\frac{\left|1 - 2\sin y-\cos x\right|}{\left|\cos x\right|} < ???
$$
How should I go about it?

Why do you want to do it this way? After canceling the $\cos y$ factor, the denominator tends to $-1$ as $(x,y) \to (\pi,\pi/2)$. It's a much cleaner argument to use the quotient rule for limits.

Allow me to pick a nit.  You have to be more careful when approaching along the line $y = \frac{\pi}{2}$ because your original expression (being of the form $\frac 00$) is undefined on that line.  So you actually need an argument to justify your transition from the original form to the form with $\cos y$ factored out of the numerator and denominator.  Having said that, as the accepted answer below demonstrates, these problems are usually straightforward if you're able to reduce to a form that is not $\frac 00$.

You have$$\left|\frac{1-2\sin(y)}{\cos(x)}-1\right|=\left|\frac{1-2\sin(y)-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}\right|$$and therefore, since$$|x-\pi|<\frac\pi3\implies|\cos(x)|\geqslant\frac12,$$you have$$|x-\pi|<\frac\pi3\implies\left|\frac{1-2\sin(y)-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}\right|\leqslant2|1-2\sin(y)-\cos(x)|.$$On the other hand, $1-2\sin(y)-\cos(x)=2(1-\sin(y))-(1+\cos(x))$. So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that:

$\delta\leqslant\frac\pi3$;
$\left|y-\frac\pi2\right|\leqslant\delta\implies|\sin(y)-1|<\frac\varepsilon8$;
$|x-\pi|\leqslant\delta\implies|\cos(x)+1|<\frac\varepsilon4$.

(Since $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R\implies|\sin(\alpha)-\sin(\beta)|,|\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\beta)|\leqslant|\alpha-\beta|$, taking $\delta=\frac\varepsilon8$ will ensure that the second and third conditions will hold.) Then,\begin{align}\left\|(x,y)-\left(\pi,\frac\pi2\right)\right\|<\delta&\implies|x-\pi|<\delta\wedge\left|y-\frac\pi2\right|<\delta\\&\implies2\bigl|2(1-\sin(x))-(1+\cos(x))\bigr|<\varepsilon\\&\implies\left|\frac{1-2\sin(y)}{\cos(x)}-1\right|<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Using that $|\sin x| \le |x|$:
$$\left|1 - 2\sin y-\cos x\right|=\left|1 - \sin y - (\sin y + \cos x)\right|
\\ \le |1-\sin y| + |\sin y + \cos x|= \\ 
2|\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{y}{2})\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{y}{2})|+2|\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2})\sin (-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2})| \\
\le 2(|\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{y}{2})|+|\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2})| \\ \le 2(\frac{|y-\frac{\pi}{2}|}{2}+\frac{|\frac{\pi}{2}+y-x|}{2}) < \delta +|(\pi-x)+(y-\frac{\pi}{2})| < 3\delta$$

Equivalently but imo more methodically, let $x=\pi+h$ and $y=\frac\pi2+k$ with $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.
$$\frac{1-2\sin y}{\cos x}=\frac{-1+2\cos k}{\cos h}=\frac{1+o(k)}{1+o(h)}=1+o(\|(h,k)\|).$$

"Given $\epsilon$, how to find delta?" question. It is not difficult but boring.
First of all let $|x-\pi|<\frac\pi6$ and $|y-\frac\pi2|<\frac\pi6$ so that $|\cos x|>\frac12$ and $\sin y>\frac12.$
The expression is then
$$\frac{|1-2\sin y-\cos x|}{|\cos x|}\\
<2|2(1-\sin y)-(\cos x +1)|\\
\leq 4|\sin y-1|+2|\cos x +1|<\epsilon$$
Set $|\sin y-1|<\frac\epsilon 4$ and $|\cos x+1|<\frac\epsilon 2.$
We may assume that $\epsilon<<1.$ And so,
$$\delta_2=\min\{\frac\pi2-\arcsin(1-\frac\epsilon 4),\frac\pi 6\}$$
altough the first number is bingo smaller,
$$\delta_1=\min\{\pi-\arccos(-1+\frac\epsilon2),\frac\pi6\}$$
and $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.
